# I have four wires when I cut ear buds away. Which ones are hot and which are going 1red 1blue 1gold and 1yellow

Tags: grounding

I cut some earbuds to use on something else and would like to know which are grounds and which are hot 1is blue 1 is red 1 is yellowish and 1 is goldish

Comment: the color coding of the wires depends on the manufacturer .... you need to determine which color connects to which part of the audio jack

Comment: Do you have access to a multimeter?  You can set it to continuity to check which colors are connected to each other, and you can also meter the part you cut off to see which wire connects to which part of the jack.  A cheap multimeter will run you anywhere from $0 to $2-20(garage sale/second hand/sale price on a low end one).

Comment: I once bought a radio for a car before the ISO standard connectors. I hacked off the wires at either end, and sat in the car for about an hour with a multimeter probing all the wires to find the 4 speaker pairs, power, ground, ignition etc. I then connected it all together with a big chocolate block. I can definitely be done.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by KH using a multimeter set on continuity. The earbuds I assume have a stereo plug. The tip of the plug is the hot terminal for the left channel. The middle ring is the hot terminal for the right channel. The longer cylinder part is the common ground for both channels. Remove a small bit of insulation from each wire and touch one of the probes of the multimeter to the plug and the other to any one of the wires in question. I hopes this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When I like to determine which wires are which, I plug in a rewirable audio jack into a device and touch the wires against each contact and listen to establish when the wires are in the right place. Then note it down, and solder away.

You need to make sure the ends of the wire have valid continuity for the test to work, so I usually burn the coating off first at the ends of each wire.